# Adding @Component to subProtocolWebSocketHandler causes No Handler exception

Tags: spring-websocket

WebSocketConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/comp-and-run");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
}

//@Bean
//@NonNull
//public WebSocketHandler subProtocolWebSocketHandler(AbstractSubscribableChannel clientInboundChannel, AbstractSubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel) {
    //return new StompSubProtocolWebSocketHandler(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel);
//}
}
```

StompSubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:

```
@Component
public class StompSubProtocolWebSocketHandler extends SubProtocolWebSocketHandler {

    public StompSubProtocolWebSocketHandler(MessageChannel clientInboundChannel, SubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel) {
        super(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel);
        // super.setDefaultProtocolHandler(new StompSubProtocolHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(@NonNull WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("connected");
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(@NonNull WebSocketSession session, @NonNull CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("disconnected");
        session.close(closeStatus);
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, closeStatus);
    }
}
```

This gives error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'stompSubProtocolWebSocketHandler'
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:957) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:611) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at com.example.ocbackend.OcBackendApplication.main(OcBackendApplication.java:9) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No handlers
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.start(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:271) ~[spring-websocket-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

When I remove the @Component and declare a bean as the commented portion in the config, it works fine.

I would like to autowire stuff in my handler for some processing but without declaring it as a component, that seems impossible.

Any way to resolve this? Or achieve the final goal without declaring it as a component?